# Good mouse tracking software that records position vs time with fairly high resolution?

Tags: windows, mouse, tracking

I'm looking to record some data about cursor movements that will be correlated with other sensor data collected by another system.  I hope to learn something about the relationship of the physical motions of a computer mouse and the cursor motion when used by the average user.

I have software to record the physical mouse that records the sensor data in a CSV file at a fairly short time interval (on the order of 100hz).  **What I need is a piece of software that can record similar data about the cursor position on the computer screen vs time intervals (faster than 30Hz sampling preferred)).**

Any suggestions?  Windows solutions preferred, but Linux/Unix solutions are acceptable.  Must be able to export tracking data in an easy to work with format like CSV.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio you can create an app that does this with a high degree of accuracy:

```
#import System.Windows.Forms
Dim LocalMousePosition as Point

LocalMousePosition = myControl.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
Debug.WriteLine("X = " & LocalMousePosition.X & ", Y = " & LocalMousePosition.Y)
```

You can use the System.Diagnostics.StopWatch to report the time. You can check the stopwatch's accuracy my looking at Stopwatch.frequency.